# Conformal Mapping #5

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

I am studying for my final exam and am really struggling on this question #5.  I have attached both the question and the answer listed in the book.  I am really trying to get the ideas down so that I do well on the final.

My attempt (Finding a conformal map of the part of the upper half-plane outside a circle of radius r onto the entire upper half plane):

I want to use a known conformal map to map the domain to the first quadrant.  I then want to use w=z^2 to map to the first quadrant to entire half plane.  Finally I want to use a linear fractional transformation that maps the upper half-plane to itself.  The only thing is I don't know how to map the domain to the first quadrant and what the linear fractional transformation should be, but this is my general idea that I am thinking.

[image]
[image]

Any help, suggestions, tips would be much welcomed, as I am struggling with these concepts.

Comment: My thinking is this: your (5.) is half of an outer annulus. The reciprocal map should take your region and make it into a half disk. Then, dilate to the unit half disk and use one of your standard maps to go from half disk to half plane. Pick three convenient points and set-up the fractional linear transformation to make that map from the half disk to the half plane... this is a sketch, I might be missing something without fleshing out the details. I bet someone works this one out for you, it sounds fun.

Comment: I see, I'm not sure I exactly follow though.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Good idea. You should write it up as an answer.

Comment: Related : [In which sense does Cauchy-Riemann equations link complex- and real analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383380/in-which-sense-does-cauchy-riemann-equations-link-complex-and-real-analysis/2042247#2042247) ,
[Potential flow around a circular cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow_around_a_circular_cylinder) ,
[a problem in application of conformal mappings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820189/a-problem-in-application-of-conformal-mappings/825670#825670) .

Comment: Related : [Potential flow around a circular cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow_around_a_circular_cylinder) , as has been used (again) as an example in : 
[Solving for streamlines from numerical velocity field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926636/solving-for-streamlines-from-numerical-velocity-field/2035770#2035770) .

Comment: What is that thing above the second $R$?

Answer (score 3):

I think you and @JamesS.Cook have some good ideas. Here's what I would do: i) $z\to z/R$ normalizes the situation. ii) the map $z\to 1/z$ then takes the exterior of the upper unit half disc to the lower unit half disc. iii) follow that with the map $z\to -z.$ Now we're in the upper unit half disc.

Now, my favorite go-to map from the full open unit disc to the right half plane is

$$z\to \frac{1+z}{1-z}.$$

This map will take the upper unit half disc to the first quadrant as you wanted. Now apply $z\to z^2$ to arrive at the final map.

Putting that together gives the map

$$f(z) = \left (\frac{z-R}{z+R}\right)^2.$$

Now that doesn't look like your map, but there are a lot of bilholomorphic self maps of the upper half plane, for example $-1/z, az$ for $a>0$ and $z+b$ for $b\in \mathbb R$ and compositions of such. So one of those composed with $f$ should give your map.